# Signs of a great SQL developer

Tags: sql

Based on their work, how do you distinguish a great SQL developer?

Examples might include:

Seldom uses CURSORs, and tries to refactor them away.
Seldom uses temporary tables, and tries to refactor them away.
Handles NULL values in OUTER JOINs with confidence.
Avoids SQL extensions that are not widely implemented.
Knows how to indent with elegance.

Comment: Will someone please clarify the comment "Seldom uses CURSORs, and tries to refactor them away."? I work on a medium sized HR system and utilize cursors on a fairly regular basis when doing bulk updates on records anywhere from a couple of thousand to tens of thousands. How would this be done without the use of a cursor?

Comment: Can you give an example of a business process operation for which you are currently using a cursor?

Comment: 2000 employees from business unit 103 have termination actions on 01-MAR-2012. I want to add a hire action for those employees on 02-MAR-2012 and update their pay records. Some of the fields on the highest records for each employee will be carried forward to the new actions and records. How would I grab those employee actions and pay records without a cursor? The system mimics a Peoplesoft system if that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't you naturally do something like SELECT fields FROM terminations WHERE business_unit = '103' AND action_date = '01-MAR-2012'? Then use that to construct "INSERT INTO hire_actions (fields....) SELECT etc." (adding joins and expressions as required? And for the pay records, SELECT from the highest record to construct the INSERT and UPDATE statements? You probably need to do roughly the same thing even with a cursor. Just make a set operation out of it to handle all the employees in one statement.

Comment: Ah. I see. The recommendation is to put all the code into one SQL statement. For simple updates that might be okay, but for programs that require more complex logic that could potentially make the SQL quite unwieldy and difficult to troubleshoot. Makes me want to go back and check over my old programs though. When I have time I think I'll go and see if some of those can be optimized. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It's not about having it in one statement, but rather about writing set-based SQL. Relational DBs are all about SET THEORY. Cursors are a type of loop, meaning that the operation works on a single row and then loops through all of the rows in your dataset. You might not notice this on a small dataset but this is extremely inefficient and works against the optimisers within the database engine. SQL is a declarative language, you tell it want you want to acheive, not how to achieve it. Cursors appeal to programmers because loops are familiar, but they don't scale in SQL; they're evil.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found that a great SQL developer is usually also a great database designer, and will prefer to be involved in both the design and implementation of the database. That's because a bad database design can frustrate and hold back even the best developer - good SQL instincts don't always work right in the face of pathological designs, or systems where RI is poor or non-existent. So, one way to tell a great SQL developer is to test them on data modeling.

Also, a great DB developer has to have complex join logic down cold, and know exactly what the results of various multi-way joins will be in different situations. Lack of comfort with joins is the #1 cause of bad SQL code (and bad SQL design, for that matter).

As for specific syntax things, I'd hesitate at directives like:

> Does not use CURSORs.
>
> Does not use temporary tables.

Use of those techniques might allow you to tell the difference between a dangerously amateur SQL programmer (who uses them when simple relational predicates would be far better) and a decent starting SQL programmer (who knows how to do most stuff without them). However, there are many situations in real world usage where temp tables and cursors are perfectly adequate ways (sometimes, the only ways) to accomplish things (short of moving to another layer to do the processing, which is sometimes better anyway).

So, use of advanced concepts like these isn't forbidden, but unless you're clearly dealing with a SQL expert working on a really tough problem that, for some reason, doesn't lend itself to a relational solution ... yeah, they're probably warning signs.

Comment: I especially like the comment in regard to mispartioned functionality. I think that's more often than not the use of cursors - the dbms is being used to solve some other layer's problem.

Comment: And, as with most things ... "it depends". Various architectural and fuzzy reasons might convince one to write code on the DB that would be more appropriate on another layer, and those are times when these advanced DB features are useful.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that cursors, temporary tables or other SQL practices are inherently bad or that their usage is a clear sign of how good a database programmer is.

I think there is the right tool for every type of problem. Sure, if you only have a hammer, everything looks like a nail. I think a great SQL programmer or database developer is a person who knows which tool is the right one in a specific situation. IMHO you can't generalize excluding specific patterns.

But a rule of thumb may be: a great database developer will find a more **short and elegant solution** for complex situations than the average programmer.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few things that don't apply to run-of-the-mill software developers, but do apply to someone with good SQL skills:

- Defines beneficial indexes, but not redundant or unused indexes.
- Employs transactions effectively.
- Values referential integrity.
- Applies normalization to database design.
- Thinks in terms of sets, not in terms of loops.
- Uses JOIN confidently.
- Knows how NULL and tri-value logic works.
- Understands the uses and benefits of query parameters.

The examples you give, of not using cursors, temp tables, or knowing 3 alternative queries for a given task, I would *not* consider indications of being a great SQL developer.  Perhaps I would call someone who does those things an "*acrobat*."

Comment: These are marks of a good SQL developer, but I don't think they're sufficient to distinguish a "great" developer.

Comment: OK, with the qualifier that there are conservative acrobats, and foolish acrobats.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant.  An acrobat can exhibit impressive artistry, skill, and talent.  But often there are easier ways to get from point A to point B.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the already great answers; The developer can **reduce a complex problem to something simple** and easy to maintain.

Comment: cool, nice general, vague, not-really-adding-any-value answer!

Answer (score 0):

Knows how to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA and table metadata in order to write either generic code or to code generate code in order to save repetitive database tasks.